# Editing a specific text on a specific line txt batch

Tags: batch-file

So the title allready says what i mean okay so this is what i mean:
So here we have some text:

```
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Online
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Online
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Online
```

So i want to edit it like this with batch:

```
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Online
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Offline
Login: Demo Password: Demo World: Demo Script: Demo Status: Online
```

And keep the text that allready was posted!
I've allready made the script where it creates the line's but the status is Online!
I need a script that you can do it like this:

```
set /p LOGIN=Please enter your login name:
set /p STATUS=Please enter a status:
::Here must be the code that change's the status
echo Account status changed!!
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own so far??

Comment: Yes! But i've just registered for stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i made it allready!!

Here is the solution:

```
  :START
cls
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f "delims=" %%x in (accounts.txt) do (
  set "Bot_!Counter!=%%x"
  set /a Counter+=1
)
set /a NumLines=Counter - 1

set Countero=1
for /f "delims=" %%x in (status.txt) do (
  set "Status_!Countero!=%%x"
  set /a Countero+=1
)

for /l %%x in (1,1,%NumLines%) do echo ID: %%x !Bot_%%x! !Status_%%x!
endlocal

set /p ID=Bot ID:
set /p REP=Status:

@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "file=status.txt"
SET /a Line#ToSearch=%ID%
SET "Replacement=%REP%"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"
cls
goto START
```

I've splitted it up in two files. accounts.txt andstatus.txt
Dont look on the variable name's because i was just solving the issue and not working on nice code :P So here you have it.